# Find an expression for $X_n = E[Y | \mathcal{F}_n]$ with $\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(\{1\}, \{2\}, \ldots, \{n-1\}, \{n, n+1, \ldots\})$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, martingales

Consider $\Omega = \mathbb{N}, \mathcal{F} = 2^{\mathbb{N}}$ and the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ defined by:

\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{P}[k] &= 2^{-k}, \; \; k = 1,2, \ldots \\
\end{align*}

Let $Y$ be the random variable:

\begin{align*}
    Y(k) &= \frac{2^{k+1}}{k^2} \\
    EY &= \int \frac{2^{k+1}}{k^2} dP = \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{3} \\
\end{align*}

Let $\mathcal{F}_n$ be the filtration:

\begin{align*}
    \mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(\{1\}, \{2\}, \ldots, \{n-1\}, \{n, n+1, \ldots\}) \\
\end{align*}

Find an expression for $X_n = E[Y | \mathcal{F}_n]$

Could someone give me a hint on how to approach this one? Thanks!

Comment: $X_n=\sum I_{A_n} \frac {EYI_{A_n}} {P(A_n)}$ where $A_i$'s are the $n$ given sets generating $\mathcal F_n$.

Comment: How did you get that solution? What theorem are you using? Thank you so much!!

Comment: That is the general formula for conditional expectation given the $\sigma$ field generated by a finite or countable partition of the sample space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) $X_n$ needs to be $\mathcal F_n$-measurable, meaning only that it must be constant on $\{n,n+1,\ldots\}$.

(2) you need to have $E[X_n\cdot 1_B]=E[Y\cdot 1_B]$ for each $B\in\mathcal F_n$. For $B=\{n,n+1,\ldots\}$ this means the constant value of $X_n$ mentioned in (1) must be
$$
b_n:={\sum_{k=n}^\infty 2k^{-2}\over \sum_{k=n}^\infty 2^{-k}}=2^n\sum_{k=n}^\infty k^{-2}.
$$
For $B=\{k\}$ (where $k$ is an element of $\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$) this means $X_n(k) = 2^{k+1}k^{-2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional expectation is defined with the property such that for any $A \in \mathcal{F}_n$, $\int_A X_n \, dP = \int_A Y \, dP$.

Consider sets of the form $A = \{k \} \in \mathcal{F}_n$ which exist for $1 \le k \le n-1$. Each $k$ forms its own atom in $\mathcal{F}_n$ so $X_n(k)$ can have a distinct value.

\begin{align*}
    X_n^{-1}(Y(k)) &= \{k\} \\
    \int_{\{k\}} X_n dP &= \int_{\{k\}} Y dP \\
    X_n(k) 2^{-k} &= Y(k) 2^{-k} \\
    X_n(k) &= Y(k) \\
\end{align*}

Consider the set of the form $A = \{ n, n+1, n+2, \ldots \} \in \mathcal{F}_n$ which exists for $n \le k$. All of these values of $k \ge n$ form one single atom in $\mathcal{F}_n$, so $X_n(k)$ must produce the same value for all such values of $k$.

\begin{align*}
    X_n^{-1}(Y(k)) &= \{ n, n+1, n+2, \ldots \} \\
    \int_{\{ n, n+1, n+2, \ldots \}} X_n dP &= \int_{\{ n, n+1, n+2, \ldots \}} Y dP \\
    \sum\limits_{k=n}^\infty X_n(k) 2^{-k} &= \sum\limits_{r=n}^\infty Y(r) 2^{-r} \\
    X_n(k) 2^{1-n} &= \sum\limits_{r=n}^\infty Y(r) 2^{-r} \\
    X_n(k) &= \sum\limits_{r=n}^\infty Y(r) 2^{n-r-1} \\
\end{align*}

Tying this together yields:

\begin{align*}
    X_n(k) &= \begin{cases}
        Y(k) & \text{if} \; 1 \le k \le n - 1 \\
        \sum\limits_{r=n}^\infty 2^{n-r-1} Y(r) & \text{if} \; n \le k \\
    \end{cases} \\
\end{align*}